# How to unset session value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Some users should redirect to their profile . 
to Prevention loop page,  I should unset user session data .
but by my code, user redirected to `/profile/settingsProfile` page then page refreshed again and again .

my code:

```
    $data['redirectToProfile'] = $this->session->userdata('redirectToProfile');
    if($data['redirectToProfile'])
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('redirectToProfile'); //not work
      //$this->session->set_userdata(array('redirectToProfile'       => false)); // not work

        redirect('/profile/settingsProfile', 'refresh');
    }
```

my code placed in before load all views.

Comment: I should unset session data .

Comment: Why I got down-vote ?!

Comment: all session or specific ??

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam just my key of sessions .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**In construct**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    ob_start();
    $this->load->library('Session');
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$redirectToProfile = $this->session->userdata('redirectToProfile');  
if(!empty($redirectToProfile))
{
    echo "Session data is :".$redirectToProfile ; 
    $this->session->unset_userdata('redirectToProfile');
    ob_clean();
    //redirect('/profile/settingsProfile');
    echo "session data is :". $redirectToProfile ;
}
else
{
    echo "empty";
}
```

Comment: I can't use redirect after using session?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter 3 and later the session tools are designed to be a UI to the web session and not their own separate thing, so you may find success using the PHP functions like session_unset and session_destroy:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php